# Using Parse and Bolts Frameworks for Back4App on tvOS

Tags: parse-platform, tvos, back4app, bolts-framework, parse-framework

I am trying to integrate the parse server hosted on back4app.com with my tvOS app. All the Github releases I have seen for Parse don't include the Parse.framework or Bolts.framework that are built for tvOS. I know it works, as there was documentation for it, but all the frameworks have been removed from the source code, and the Bolts.framework I have for other apps won't work, as it was built for iOS not tvOS. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to install Parse and Bolts frameworks using Cocoapods?
I just tried and it worked quite well.

Also, you can try to download Bolts from here:
https://www.back4app.com/docs/ios/manual-integration

and check if it works for you.